# How do I order the friends list returned from the new Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

You can get a list of friends of an authenticated user with:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends

Anyone have any idea how to order the list by user name? Because it doesn't by default. There's nothing in the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured out a solution. Eventually, we'll probably be able to order graph results. For now, I'm just doing this (javascript). Assuming that I got "fb_uid" from my PHP session:

```js
var friends = FB.Data.query("SELECT name, uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1={0}) ORDER BY name", parseInt(fb_uid));
friends.wait(function(rows){
    console.log(rows);
});
```

Answer (score 12):

we do this in several apps just by sorting in javascript.

```js
function sortByName(a, b) {
    var x = a.name.toLowerCase();
    var y = b.name.toLowerCase();
    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
}

var _friend_data = null
function lazy_load_friend_data(uid) {
  if (_friend_data == null) {    
    FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {        
        _friend_data = response.data.sort(sortByName);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: lots of possibilities, but one possibly terrible idea would be to return a random -1,1,0 in the above sort function :)

Answer (score 3):

I think the whole OpenGraph API is still in a bit of a transitional stage from FB Connect. In any case, I would just do a good old order-by query in FQL, which you can still use.  I can't imagine it will be too hard to change once the open graph way of doing this gets established.

This very good tutorial shows you how to do it:

http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/

```php
$fql    =   "select name, hometown_location, sex, pic_square from user where uid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$param  =   array(
        'method'     => 'fql.query',
        'query'      => $fql,
        'callback'   => ''
);
$fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);
```

Comment: You're right. I figured out how to do a FQL query with the new API. posting answer now.

Answer (score 2):

What is the problem if you do it on caller side. That means, after you get all friends from that graph API, you can put all of them into a sorted data structure and then display all of them:)

Comment: This solution doesn't seem so bad that I received a minus. If you can not do it on facebook server side using GraphAPI, you will have to deal with it yourself? right?

Comment: Agreed, I neutralized the -1. =) But I think the Graph API is lacking here. Some sorts can't be done by the caller. Like most interacted with friends first. Or by surname.

Comment: the problem is that you can't use the limit and offset parameters if you want the alphabetically sorted first two friends and nothing more

Answer (score 2):

Using FQL in one call.

```
SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN 
(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) 
ORDER BY name ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
$friends = $facebook->api('me/friends');
foreach ($friends as $key=>$value) {
    sort($value);
    foreach ($value as $fkey=>$fvalue) {
      echo "<img src='https://graph.facebook.com/".$fvalue[id]."/picture' width='50' height='50' title='".$fvalue[name]."' />";     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for me a simple asort($friends); worked fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
private function _compareFacebookFriends($a, $b)
{
    return strcasecmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
}

public function sortFacebookFriendsArray(&$array)
{
    usort($array, '_compareFacebookFriends');
}

/* Add here $facebook's initialization. Use Facebook PHP SDK */
$fbFriends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
sortFacebookFriendsArray($fbFriends);
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off of @MainSocial's answer, but sorting by last then first name, instead of first name only:

```js
function sortByName(a, b) {
    var fn = function(x) { return x.name.toLowerCase(); };
    var ln = function(x) { return x.last_name.toLowerCase(); };
    if(ln(a) == ln(b)){
        if(fn(a) == fn(b)) {
            return 0;
        }
        return (fn(a) < fn(b)) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return (ln(a) < ln(b)) ? -1 : 1;
}

function getFriendsList() {
    FB.api('/me/friends', {fields: 'name,id,last_name'}, function(response) {
        var friends = response.data.sort(sortByName);
        for (i=0; i<friends.length; i++) {
            $('body').append(friends[i].name + ' - ' + friends[i].id + '<br>');
        }
    });
}

getFriendsList()
```