# Order facebook friends list response

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am listing facebook friends so:

```
FB.api('/me/friends?fields=id,name,updated_time&date_format=U&<?=$access_token?>',
                    {limit:3,
                    function(response){      console.log('Friend name: '+response.data[0].name);
                    }
    );
```

But I would like to be able to customize (random prefered) the order, how can i do this?

Please Note: [i don't want to randomize the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862285/how-do-i-order-the-friends-list-returned-from-the-new-facebook-graph-api), i want to get a randomized response.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What part of the accepted solution for the SO post you link to isn't acceptable? Using [`FB.Data.query`](http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FB.Data.query) allows you to specify any order you'd like (including [`ORDER BY rand()`](http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FQL)).

EDIT

Don't actually know if this works, but you basically want this:

```
FB.api('/fql?q={"all+friends":"SELECT+id,+name,+profile_update_time+FROM+user+WHERE+id+IN+(SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1+=+me())"}&date_format=U&<?=$access_token?>',
  ...
);
```

The important part is the FQL query:

```
SELECT id, name, profile_update_time FROM user WHERE id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

Comment: Sure, use `Fb.api` to run an [`FQL` query](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/).

Comment: Would you mind adding the code to your answer? thank you very mucho

Comment: There's plenty of well-documented sample code, but I'll take a stab at it.

Comment: You missed the ORDER part, can I just place a ORDER BY RAND() there?

Comment: Whoops! Yeah `ORDER BY rand()` in the outer `WHERE`-clause should work.

Comment: Thanks for your time, will try and let you know ;)